# Laravel Eloquent Ignore Casing

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, case-insensitive

I am trying to run a query using Eloquent
the $vars['language'] is in lower case but the language column is not necessarily in lower case. How can i do this search using eloquent but still have the lower case in the query

```
Item::where('language', $vars['language'])
```

What i want to do is this even though i can't find anywhere how to do this

```
Item::where('LOWER(language)', $vars['language'])
```

so that they are both in lowercase and then i can get them to match.

Comment: Use DB:raw() to use LOWER()

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use whereRaw with [parameter binding](https://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries) to sanitize your whereRaw statement:

```
$term = strtolower($vars['language']);
Item::whereRaw('lower(language) like (?)',["%{$term}%"])->get();
```

**Prev answer**
In some dabases you can use operator `ilike` in your where. For example

```
Item::where('language', 'ilike', $vars['language'])->get();
```

All available operators are:

```
protected $operators = array(
    '=', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '<>', '!=',
    'like', 'not like', 'between', 'ilike',
    '&', '|', '^', '<<', '>>',
);
```

Edit: `ilike` is case-insensitive `like`.

Comment: hey what is ilike and what does it do?

Comment: ilike is postgres case insensitive like

Comment: so you mean `like` is  a case insensitive operator?

Comment: what does like has to do with the case sensitivity?

Comment: Where did you get the list of operators from? `regex` should be included as well.

Comment: nice to see you just copied my `whereRaw` answer into yours, keeping the `like` idea that doesn't even have much to do with what was asked.

Answer (score 23):

As per [this post](http://laravel.io/forum/08-19-2014-case-insensitive-search-with-eloquent), a db-independent way to solve this would be:

```
Item::whereRaw('LOWER(language) = ?', [$vars['language']])->get();
```