# Ignore accent in multiple search request

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I would like to know how can I ignore the accent in multiple search with eloquent from Laravel.

Currently I have this :

```
// $searchTerms => 'Héllo human';
$explodedTerms = explode(" ", $searchTerms); 

...

// $explodedTerms => ['Héllo', 'human'];
$query->where(function ($q) use ($explodedTerms) {
    foreach ($explodedTerms as $value) {
        $q->whereRaw('LOWER(`text`) LIKE ?', ['%'.strtolower($value).'%' ]);
        }
    });
...
```

I would like to have the search terms 'hello human' to match the field text.

I tried with ILIKE but I have an error :

```
$q->whereRaw('LOWER(`text`) ILIKE ?', ['%'.strtolower($value).'%' ]);
```

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ILIKE

Comment: Perhaps this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4126152/5159168

Comment: Thx @Andreas for your answer. I tried with this solution, but I have the result "h'ello"... no match with the field 'text'.

Comment: `ILIKE`? You like?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel https://stackoverflow.com/a/21216559/5453732, but with whereRaw doesn't work.. I think that it's logic that doesn't work with whereRaw...

Comment: @JérémieChazelle - I've never heard of `ILIKE` in MySQL - And it doesn't make much sense. The default COLLATION in MySQL configuration and laravel settings is case insensitive (`eg. utf8mbr4_unicode_ci`). With a CI collation any `LIKE` and any `=` search is always case insensitive. `SELECT 'E' = 'e'` will return TRUE by default. Also `SELECT 'E' = 'é'`. So you usually don't need to do anything. If the simple LIKE doesn't work, post your column collation.

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer 
$str = iconv('utf-8','ASCII//IGNORE',$str);